# Rauch filter (or) MFB filter - Input interfacing

Tags: filter, fpaa

How to interface single ended input signal to inputs of the MFB filter or Rauch filter?

[image]

Is it okay to grounding the reference of the input signal rather connecting it to 2nd input terminal?

Note: I got this circuit from Anadigm's [FPAA Quad board manual](http://www.anadigm.com/_doc/um231004-k001.pdf)

Comment: Why not just use a single ended MFB filter?

Comment: So we can interface both the single ended and differential input as well. Also this filter converts the single ended input in to differential output, why because Anadigm FPAA process every signals in differential manner only. @Andyaka